# How can one set a cookie with a token using apollo server?

Tags: cookies, apollo-server

I want to set token to cookies after user logged in on the website.

I found this [apollo-server-plugin-http-headers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-plugin-http-headers)  package.

So I'm trying to do this in my resolver.

```
async loginUser(_, { loginInput }, context) {
            ...

            const token = generateToken(user);

            context.setCookies.push({
                name: "cookieName",
                value: token,
                options: {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    maxAge: 3600,
                    path: "/",
                    sameSite: true,
                    secure: true
                }
            });

            console.log(context, 123)

            return {
                ...
                token
            }
```

In setting up apollo server in

```
    const httpHeadersPlugin = require("apollo-server-plugin-http-headers");

    const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    plugins: [httpHeadersPlugin],
    context: {
        setHeaders: new Array(),
        setCookies: new Array(),
    }
});
```

I'm checking browsers cookies tab, in Chrome application -> cookies, but nothing is set there. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong? Maybe there is another way to do it?

All the help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the cookie option `secure` for localhost, i.e. in development mode. Try setting `secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`

That is:

```js
context.setCookies.push({
  name: "cookieName",
  value: token,
  options: {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 3600,
    path: "/",
    sameSite: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  }
});
```

Trying to do cookies with schema stitching was a bear for me to figure out.  For a deeper dive you can [check out this repo](https://github.com/ptpaterson/netlify-faunadb-graphql-auth/blob/master/functions/graphql.js) which uses the `apollo-server-plugin-http-headers` plugin.